# Ember.js: Back button doesn't refresh index view when using nested routes

Tags: ember.js

http://jsfiddle.net/bugsinamber/xjvYk/6/

#### Setup

I have an index view with a list of stories. This gets rendered into the application outlet. When I click on each story, a story view gets rendered into the same outlet (replacing the index view). I'm using nested routes.

#### Issue

When I click on "all stories" to go back to index view from story view, it works fine. But if hit the browser back button to go back to the index view, the path changes to "/stories" correctly and yet the index view doesn't render. I have to hit the back button one more time for the index view to render.

#### The template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    {{outlet}}    
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="stories">
    <p>Stories Index Page</p>    
    {{#each story in controller}}
    {{#linkTo "story"}}
    {{story.title}}
    {{/linkTo}}
    {{/each}}   
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="story">
   {{#linkTo "index"}}Back to all stories{{/linkTo}}

   {{title}}    
    <p>Story test page</p>
</script>
```

#### The app.js

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("stories", function() {
        this.resource("story", {path: ':story_id'});
    }); 
});

App.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Story.find();   
  }
});

App.StoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Story.find(params.story_id);
  },  
  renderTemplate: function() {
      this.render('story', {   // the template to render
          into: 'application' // the template to render into
      });   
  }
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    this.transitionTo('stories');
  } 
});
```

#### What I know so far

This works correctly if I don't use nested routes. Apparently I shouldn't use nested routes if I'm not nesting my views, but that limits the design needs. Logically, I should be allowed to use nested routes in this case.

I'm nesting the routes because I need to access "stories" from the story controller like shown below. If I don't nest the routes, then when I load the story view first (without loading the index view yet), then "posts" doesn't return anything.

```
App.StoryController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: "stories", 
    previousPost: function() {
        return this.advancePost(1);
    },
    nextPost: function() {
        return this.advancePost(-1);
    },
    advancePost: function(delta) {
        var index, length, posts;
        posts = this.get('controllers.stories');
        length = posts.get('length');
        index = (posts.indexOf(this.get('content')) + delta + length) % length;
        if (index >= 0 && index < length) {
            return this.transitionToRoute('story', posts.objectAt(index));
        }

    }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said it, they shouldn't be nested. What do you mean by limits the design?  You get the same result without nesting them, only without the errors.  Also you wouldn't waste an `App.Store.find()` request that you don't need if you remove the nesting.

Comment: Hi Teddy, just edited my original post to show you why I'm nesting the routes. Please do let me know if the same can be achieved without nesting.

Answer (score 2):

Your routes should be nested according to your UI.  `stories` and `story` template are not nested, so just do:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource("stories");
  this.resource("story", { path: ':story_id' }); 
});
```

If you want the `story` URL to include `stories`, you can do:

```
  this.resource("story", { path: 'stories/:story_id' });
```

Next, you want to access all the stories in `App.StoryController`.  That does not mean that it needs to be nested inside the `stories` resource, or that you need to use `App.StoriesController`.

You want to access the data, so get the data and set it in `App.StoryController`:

```
App.StoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    controller.setProperties({
      model: model,
      stories: App.Story.find()
    });
  },
  model: function(params) {
    return App.Story.find(params.story_id);
  }
});
```

And keep the `App.StoriesRoute` route the same, as a separate route, that is not related to `App.StoryRoute`.

```
App.StoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.Story.find();   
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Teddy, couldn't figure out what I need to modify in the Story controller. "posts = this.get('controllers.stories');" is still returning nothing when the index view hasn't been rendered yet. I tried "posts = this.get('stories')" but that didn't work either. Thank you again.

Comment: `posts  = this.get('stories')` should work.  I had a typo, use `App.Story.find()` instead of `App.Store.find()` in `App.StoryRoute` `setupController`.

Comment: Hi, turns out the error for this.get('stories') was actually coming from another line I'd forgotten to comment out. All works, thank you!